# Export ASP Chart control to Word document

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to export asp chart control to word document using asp.net?

[image]

I have to export this chart to Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution.

First i saved the chart as  Png image.

```
         Chart1.SaveImage(@"D:\Test\Sample1.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Then Exported the PNG image to word.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(); //If you're creating a document
        oWord.Visible = true;
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        var oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        oPara1.Range.Text = "Chart Sample";
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        System.Drawing.Image Picture = myimage;*// Assigned saved png image*
        var oPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetImage(Picture));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        oPara2.Range.Paste();
        oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        oDoc.SaveAs(docFilePath);
        oDoc.Close();
        oWord.Quit();
```